# Showing $(0,0,0)$ is not a saddle point of $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^3$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the function
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2-z^3$$
I found out $(0,0,0)$ is its critical point. The Hessian at this point is equal to zero so it's inconclusive but it's very easy tho show that $(0,0,0)$ is not the maximum or the minimum of $f$.

However, according to Wolfram Alpha, $f$ has no saddle points. So, how am I supposed to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha is wrong. Consider $f(0,0,z)$ to see that $(0,0,0)$ is a saddle point.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't get it. How do I see this?

Comment: @mvfs314 Take $\varepsilon>0$. So, $f(0,0,\varepsilon)=-\varepsilon^3<0=f(0,0,0)<\epsilon^3=f(0,0,-\varepsilon)$.